# Running while loop to open new chrome window

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am running Selenium IDE and trying to write a while loop to open a new chrome window after closing one. I had several attempts with select windows but still unable to run the loop repeatedly.

Here is what I have:
[image]

Error:
while on ${var}<=2 Failed:
A window was not selected after closing the previous one, aborting playback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error appears because of wrong iterator. `execute script | ${var} +1 |` command doesn't increase variable `var`. This command should be replaced with `execute script | return Number(${var}) +1; | var`

Also You forget to select root window after closing new tab. So after the 10th command should be added `select window | handle=${root} |`